# Working on iOS emulator, but not on phone (Phonegap and Google maps API)

Tags: google-maps, ios6, cordova, emulation

I'm using Google Maps API and Phonegap to connect to a server and receive information and coordinates from a SQL database.

It works perfectly when I run the emulator on Xcode, but when I run it on my device (iPhone 4S 6.1) I get database errors.

Any ideas as to why this might be?

I can supply code if needed.

Comment: are you by any chance using a local db on the pc and trying to access it on phone ? what are the debug errors ?

Comment: The DB is on a server (SQL and PHP). The error is "Database Error: undefined". The fact it works perfectly on the emulator and not on the phone is what stumps me..